# Asp.net ImageButton set to visible = false. Still shows grey border

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton

I am using an asp.net image button control. On page load I have the button set to:

`imgbtn.visible = false;`

It's not showing the image. However it still displays a gray border rectangle where the button should be. I have also tried setting  a style of

`border : none;`

It still shows a grey rectangle where the button should be.

Is this normal?
Is there a work around?

Comment: show us some output-html code :) but you can solve the mistery on your own if you use a dom-inspector (like firebug, or developer tools) - just select the area ...

Comment: Is the button inside another styled element, such as a div?

Comment: 1. `visible` is not a property. `Visible` is however. 2. if `Visible = false` it does not render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are hiding the image using javascript, try setting the css style `display` to `'none'`:

```
imgbtn.style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care keeping the border, directly in your ASP.net page,

- Set it like that :

  ```
  <asp:Image ID="image1" runat="server" Border="0" />
  ```
- Or;

  ```
  <asp:Image ID="image1" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0" />
  ```

If you want to keep borders, just do the same stuff when setting your image `visible = false;` in your code-behind.